# Host and Stream my own videos (2019 best solutions) (small company)

Tags: web-apps, streaming

I would like to provide a service that involves hosting and streaming videos but I don't want to use third party video hosting services because I don't want to end up vendor locked.

Do hosting services provide specific media hosting or how does this work?

For example, I know that if I want to create a website I can have a MySQL database and a Node.js back/front-end server hosted by anyone really and boom, I have a website.

If I wanted to create a website that streamed videos, do I store videos in a MySQL database? what is best practice for fast retrieval?

As you can tell I am very lost when it comes to this subject and I would appreciate any insight as to best practices for hosting and streaming video (I have read through some articles but the reason I posted this is because technologies are changing all the time).

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Try resources from Zype - I believe they have, or were working on a developer tool kit, that is supposed to be helpful for the community/free without needing to purchase or buy into their products. Might speak to this.